# Custom String Deficiency

Tags: c++, string, char, comparison

So my problem currently is when I do a comparison with a modified string value, and a string value that has not been modified, I do not get the expected result of **true**, but a **false**. I have overloaded the logical comparison operator, but that's not what I want to do, this will not help solve my answer, but it does work, but when I use it in a **std::map** it doesn't work.

Edit: What I need to know is what std::map uses to logically compare the two objects through it's iteration.

**String.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum Pos
{
    BEGINNING,
    ENDING
};

class String
{
public:
    char *chars;

    String();
    String(char *chars);
    String(const char *chars);
    String(unsigned int size);

    unsigned int Length();
    String SubStr(unsigned int start, unsigned int end);
    String SubStr(unsigned int start);
    unsigned int HasStr(const char *chars);
    unsigned int HasStrInv(const char *chars);
    int FindFirst(const char *chars, Pos pos);
    int FindLast(const char *chars, Pos pos);
    std::vector<String> Split(const char *delimeter);

    String operator+(const char *chars);
    String operator=(const char *chars);
    String operator+=(const char *chars);
    bool operator==(const char *chars);
    bool operator==(String str);
    operator char*();

    static bool Equals(const char *a, const char *b);
    static unsigned int Length(const char *chars);
    static String Concate(const char *a, const char *b);
};

String operator+(const char *a, String b);
bool operator==(const char *a, String b);
```

**String.cpp**

```
#include "String.h"

String::String()
    : chars("")
{
}

String::String(char *chars)
{
    this->chars = chars;
}

String::String(const char *chars)
{
    this->chars = const_cast<char *>(chars);
}

String::String(unsigned int size)
{
    chars = new char[size];
}

unsigned int String::Length()
{
    return Length(chars);
}

String String::SubStr(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{
    unsigned int size = ((++end) - start) + 1;
    char *buffer = new char[size];
    for (unsigned int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        buffer[i - start] = chars[i];
    }
    buffer[size - 1] = '\0';
    return String(buffer);
}

String String::SubStr(unsigned int start)
{
    unsigned int size = (Length() - start);
    char *buffer = new char[size];
    for (unsigned int i = start; i < Length(); i++)
    {
        buffer[i - start] = chars[i];
    }
    buffer[size] = '\0';
    return String(buffer);
}

unsigned int String::HasStr(const char * chars)
{
    unsigned int d = 0, count = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(this->chars); ++i)
    {
        if (this->chars[i] == chars[d])
        {
            ++d;
            if (d >= strlen(chars))
            {
                ++count;
                d = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

unsigned int String::HasStrInv(const char * chars)
{
    bool greater = false;
    unsigned int i, d = 0, start = 0, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Length(); ++i)
    {
        if (this->chars[i] == chars[d])
        {
            d++;
            if (d >= strlen(chars))
            {
                if (greater)
                {
                    greater = false;
                    ++count;
                }
                start = i + 1;
                d = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            greater = true;
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    if (start - 1 < Length() - 1)
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int String::FindFirst(const char * chars, Pos pos)
{
    unsigned int d = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(this->chars); ++i)
    {
        if (this->chars[i] == chars[d])
        {
            ++d;
            if (d >= strlen(chars))
            {
                switch (pos)
                {
                case Pos::BEGINNING:
                    return i - (strlen(chars) - 1);
                    break;
                case Pos::ENDING:
                    return i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int String::FindLast(const char * chars, Pos pos)
{
    unsigned int d = strlen(chars) - 1;
    for (unsigned int i = strlen(this->chars); i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (this->chars[i] == chars[d])
        {
            --d;
            if (d >= strlen(chars))
            {
                switch (pos)
                {
                case Pos::BEGINNING:
                    return i;
                case Pos::ENDING:
                    return i + (strlen(chars) - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d = strlen(chars) - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

std::vector<String> String::Split(const char *delimeter)
{
    unsigned int size = HasStrInv(delimeter);
    std::vector<String> buffer(size);

    bool greater = false;
    unsigned int i, d = 0, start = 0, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Length(); ++i)
    {
        if (this->chars[i] == delimeter[d])
        {
            d++;
            if (d >= strlen(delimeter))
            {
                if (greater)
                {
                    greater = false;
                    buffer[count++] = SubStr(start, i - strlen(delimeter));
                }
                start = i + 1;
                d = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            greater = true;
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    if (start - 1 < Length() - 1)
    {
        buffer[count] = SubStr(start, Length() - 1);
    }
    return buffer;
}

String String::operator+(const char *chars)
{
    return Concate(this->chars, chars);
}

String String::operator=(const char *chars)
{
    this->chars = const_cast<char *>(chars);
    return *this;
}

String String::operator+=(const char * chars)
{
    this->chars = Concate(this->chars, chars);
    return *this;
}

bool String::operator==(const char * chars)
{
    return Equals(this->chars, chars);
}

bool String::operator==(String str)
{
    return Equals(chars, str);
}

String::operator char*()
{
    return chars;
}

bool String::Equals(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (Length(a) == Length(b))
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Length(a); ++i)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

unsigned int String::Length(const char * chars)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (chars[i] != '\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

String String::Concate(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    unsigned int size = strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1;
    char *buffer = new char[size];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(a); ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (unsigned int i = strlen(a); i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = b[i - strlen(a)];
    }
    buffer[size - 1] = '\0';
    return String(buffer);
}

String operator+(const char *a, String b)
{
    return String::Concate(a, b);
}

bool operator==(const char *a, String b)
{
    return String::Equals(a, b);
}
```

**Example Modified**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    String s = "Textures/SpaceShip.png";
    String a = s.SubStr(s.FindLast("/", Pos::ENDING) + 1);

    if (a.chars == "SpaceShip.png")
    {
        std::cout << "Equals" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Equals" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Not Equals
```

**Example Un-Modified**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    String s = "Textures/SpaceShip.png";
    String a = "Textures/SpaceShip.png";

    if (s.chars == a.chars)
    {
        std::cout << "Equals" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Equals" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Equals
```

**TextureManager.cpp**

```
#include "TextureManager.h"

std::map<char *, Texture2D> TextureManager::textures;

Texture2D * TextureManager::GetTexture(String path)
{
    auto it = textures.find(path);
    if (it == textures.end())
        throw new std::exception("LWE: Texture not found. " + path);
    return &it->second;
}

void TextureManager::DeleteTexture(String path)
{
    auto it = textures.find(path);
    if (it == textures.end())
        throw new std::exception("LWE: Texture not found. " + path);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &it->second.id);
    textures.erase(it);
}

void TextureManager::InsertTexture2D_PNG(String filePath)
{
    Texture2D texture;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;

    FileInfo fi = IOManager::ReadFile(filePath);

    if (decodePNG(data, texture.width, texture.height, (unsigned char *)fi.data, fi.size, true) != 0)
        throw new std::exception("Failed to decode png." + filePath);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture.id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    textures.insert(std::make_pair(filePath.SubStr(filePath.FindLast("/", Pos::ENDING) + 1), texture));
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `if(s == a)`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that. Using the overload will not help std::map.

Comment: In your example, you are comparing char* with char* which is not equal, unless they both point to the same address... or maybe I am just confused?

Comment: Added another example with a unmodified version. For any of you looking, I would suggest looking at the SubStr Method.

Comment: @Red-XIII Why wouldn't it help `std::map`? `std::map` uses `a == b`, not `a.chars == b.chars`.

Comment: Be warned that in that latter case your compiler may (helpfully) be storing the two strings at the same address. Try with a `char str1[40]` and an explicit `strcpy`.

Comment: .. `this->chars = chars` is almost certainly not what you want. To store a copy of a string, use `strdup`.

Comment: @immibis Because using the String Object in std::map will be useless. Instead I use the Chars from the String Object.

Comment: @Red-XIII Why is using the string object in std::map useless?

Comment: @Red-XIII *You can't* override how comparing two `char*`s works, by the way. `a.chars == b.chars` will always be true iff they are equal pointers.

Comment: Because std::map doesn't use the comparison operator when it iterates through the array. Trust me I already tried.

Comment: @Jongware I'm starting to see what you mean, but this doesn't solve my issue. Fyi strdup still uses the same address in memory, but my output changed strangely enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::map doesn't use `operator ==` it uses `operator <`. You need to implement that operator to be able to use your `String` type as the key of a map.

Here is an example - note the `const` of the parameter and the function - this is required by `std::map`. In this case this means you also need to change `Length` to `const`:

```
bool String::operator < (const String &str) const
{
    unsigned int myLength = Length();
    unsigned int strLength = str.Length();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myLength && i < strLength; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] < str.chars[i])
            return true;
        else if (chars[i] > str.chars[i])
            return false;
    }

    if (myLength < strLength)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

and to use it:

```
std::map<String, int> myMap;

myMap["abc"]++;
myMap["abc"]++;
myMap["def"]++;

for (auto & entry : myMap)
{
    std::cout << entry.first.chars << ":" << entry.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You're awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. +1 for the example. Nvm I can't give rep.

Comment: How so? Did you get an error message, or it didn't behave as expected?

Comment: Okay I did some more debugging on the issue. If I do it without using SubStr it works perfectly fine, however if I do, it has the tendency of never finding the value.

Comment: Can you show your code that you are trying - they may be some bug in the `<` operator - I didn't test it extensively. Maybe put it as an addition to your question.

Comment: Done, fair warning there's some OpenGL context in it.

Comment: Don't make your map on `char *` make it on `String`

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare two strings using (s.chars == a.chars), which compares the addresses of two pointers, and it always returns false for two different string objects.

Comment: Yeah I just recently discovered that, thank you for your time though. Unfortunately this still doesn't solve my error.

Comment: What I need to know is what std::map uses to logically compare the two objects through it's iteration.

Comment: You have other issues, Usually String(const char *chars) makes a copy of the chars, not taking its address.